# To disable back button in popup window

Tags: javascript

In the below code I have JavaScript function for disable function in pop window in master page but it is not disabling the back button. Please help me to solve the issue.
Pop.master

```
window.onload = function () {
    noBack();
}
function noBack() {
    this.history.forward();
}
```

Comment: this looks really spam siteish.

Comment: No. No. No. From a usability perspective, disabling the back button  on a webpage is a bad idea. It promotes behaviour like @Phil mentioned, and just comes off as annoying. What are you trying to do that you need to disable the back button?

Comment: @Dylan Corriveau Yes i need to disable back button

Comment: Even sites that process credit cards and handle sensitive information know that altering the browser behavior is just a bad idea. Put warnings on the page, use nagware in the onunload, but for crying out loud express to your business analysts in clear terms that it is **BAD** to mess with accepted user interface in this way.

Comment: Let me know your website address so I can avoid it and also report it as spam. :)

Comment: @Developer My question is why do you need it? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that ; you shouldn't do it because of causing bad user engagement. It also makes your  page untrustable.

But for chrome and firefox this should be work;

Put This script on head of your page and change 'pagename' to your page name.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
});
</script>
```

Note: This script must be on head of your page.